# How to access dynamic type before super.init in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I would like to access dynamic type of a class inside the initializer before `super.init()` is called. I think it is not possible. But the dynamic class is something that should be known at compile time inside the super class. It's just something that Swift compiler does not give access to. Or is there a way?

```
typealias JSONDict = [String: Any]

class BaseItem: NSObject {
    class var apiName: String { return "n/a" }

    init?(json: JSONDict) {
        // I need to access dynamic type before super.init().
        // I can only access current type statically.
        print("api name before: " + BaseItem.apiName)
        // Prints "n/a", I need it to print "book".

        super.init()

        // This correctly prints "book".
        print("api name: " + type(of: self).apiName)
    }
}

class Book: BaseItem {
    override class var apiName: String { return "book" }
}

let b = Book(json: [:])
```

This sample code can be copied into a playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type(of: self)` in the init method even before the instance is fully initialized:

```
typealias JSONDict = [String: Any]

class BaseItem: NSObject {
    class var apiName: String { return "n/a" }

    init?(json: JSONDict) {
        print("api name: " + type(of: self).apiName)
        super.init()
    }
}

class Book: BaseItem {
    override class var apiName: String { return "book" }
}

let b = Book(json: [:])
// api name: book
```

Comment: Wow! I swear I saw a warning using self before it has been initialized in my project and did not try it in sample playground. I tried it in the project, and it works. Or I might not even try it, because my brain knows that you can not use self before it is initalized. I feel stupid. Thanks for the answer!